# " could not find or load main class " cmd, windows 10, jdk1.8.0_11

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.*;

class sample

{

    public static void main(String arg[])

    {

        System.out.println("Here it is!");

    }

}
```

How to resolve this Error? I tried `set path="..."` and `set classpath="..."` But nothing helped me. Can you help me?

Comment: have you saved this with the name "sample.java"?

Comment: name of class containing main method and the file name should be same.

Answer (score 1):

mabye you can point the system of where the jdk is. to do this on windows 10, search environment variables in the search bar and click on **edit the system environment variables**. when you open it, click on environment variables.. at the bottom. you should see 2 sections. in the lower section click new. for the name type JAVA_HOME. it is necessary to have caps but dont include the dot. and for the path, put the directory of the java jdk. always put the folder of the latest version.

Comment: Yes. i created the Variale name and set the directory to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\". but the problem still persist.. :P

Comment: did you put the ""? because that could cause problems. also can you please vote up. thanks. i do not know what could cause the problem. if you are using eclipse to make a program in java, try to reinstall the jdk or reinstall eclipse.

Comment: did you do the above?? or just try to make a new class file and copy everything to the new file. be carefull with the names of the files and stuff

Answer (score 0):

This happens because filename of the java file is not same as your class name.
In your case file name must be "*sample.java*".
If you have multiple classes in this file, file name must contains the class that holds the main method.
Make sure you use capital/simple letters correctly.

Comment: class name and file name are same. :)

Comment: @AkhilTMohan - No they aren't!  The class name is >>different to<< the source (".java") filename and it is also >>different<< to the compiled (".class").